# Traffic light sumo simulation

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, yolo, traffic, yolov8

I have python AI YOLO model that use 4 cameras in each road to manage traffic light Based on number of cars in each road... Can i simulation this model in SUMO ?

Is there any possible to simulate this in sumo

Or if there's any other way to simulation this model

Comment: I think you will have to try to use `SUMO` on your own.